# predict_proba in sklearn classification returns different number of columns

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I'm still a beginner in scikit learn.

At this moment, I'm exploring prediction probability in classification using dataset that contains > 90000 rows, there are 12 attribute columns & 1 target column. The target column itself, contains 27 classes.

The ordinat encoder, label encoder, fit, & predict process work fine, no error
however, but when I tried .predict_proba, the result is array with 26 columns.

I got confused here, I think, the predict_proba should return array with 27 columns (same as quantity of classes in target column), not 26.

Does anyone also experience this?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check whether each of the 27 categories appear in the output variable in the training set at least once? It is possible that one of the categories has low frequency and you are not stratifying, said category could be missing from the training dataset

Comment: I just checked that one of the categories in the training output variable have 0 frequency. While in the testing output variable, there are three categories with 0 frequency.

Comment: You can solve the problem by using stratification. If you are using [https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html](`train_test_split`), you can specify the stratify parameter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.